# How to call javascript function in module

Tags: javascript, html, require

I get an Uncaught ReferenceError for generateChart.

I've defined generateChart in Chart.js which is referenced in require.config.js.

I'm new to javascript and require so this is a newbee question.

Here is my code:

main html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>

<p id="example">

<script src="js/require.config.js"></script>
<script data-main="js/config.js" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>


</body>
```

require.config.js

```html
var require = {
    paths: {
        'd3': 'lib/d3',
        'Chart' : 'Chart'
    }
};
```

config.js which contains the main entry point and the unreferenced call to generateChart

```html
define([
    'd3',
    'Chart'
], function (d3, Chart) {
    'use strict';


 d3.csv("sp500.csv", function(data) {

   d3.select("#example")
       .datum(data)
     .call(generateChart());
 });

});
```

And Chart.js where I define generateChart

```html
define([
    'd3'
], function (d3) {
    'use strict';

    generateChart = function() {
    };

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not require.js user, but it looks that dependencies are passed into the function you specify inside the `define`.
This way the second parameter in the code below should represent `Chart` module and you need to use it to call the `generateChart`:

```
define([
    'd3',
    'Chart'
], function (d3, Chart) {    /// Second parameter is 'Chart'
    'use strict';


    d3.csv("sp500.csv", function(data) {

    d3.select("#example")
        .datum(data)
        .call(Chart.generateChart());   /// use it here to call generateChart()
    });

});
```

Second issue is that Chart.js should return an object and not just define a function:

```
define([
    'd3'
], function (d3) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        generateChart: function() {
           alert('here');
        }
    }

 });
```

Comment: A reasonable observation, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @ChuckCarlson there is one more issue - your Chart module should return an object which is then passed as dependency.